# PHP array to JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to use this array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $outlet_name[] = $row['outlet_name']; 
    }
```

into a variable like this

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL"
];
```

I'm not sure of how to best do that? I'm new to all of this so if you please give me some help I'm very appreciate

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` the array after your loop, and output the `JSON`:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $outlet_name[] = $row['outlet_name']; 
}
?>
<script>
    var availableTags = <?= json_encode($outlet_name) ?>;
</script>
<?php
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
var availableTags = [
<?php foreach($outlet_name as $name){
    echo $name.",";
}?>
];
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $outlet_name[] = $row['outlet_name']; 
}    

echo 'var availableTags = ' . json_encode($outlet_name) . ';';
```